# Series value from object to int?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, series

How do you change series values from objects to ints?

Problem is:

`df[df[“Column”] == int]` works but `df[df[“Column”].between(int1,int2, inclusive = True)` doesn't work.

I believe this is because some values in series are int but some are obj such as “2005/xb9”

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this is happening is because most object classes have a == operator, but not every object type has a .between method. What you could do to solve this is check to make sure the type is what you think it should be before you do an operation.

For example if you needed df["Column"] to be an int in order to use the .between method, you could use the `type()` function and only proceed if it is the type you think it is.

```
if type(df["Column"]) == 'int':
    df[df[“Column”].between(int1,int2, inclusive = True)]
```

---

If you were instead looking to filter things out of the set, I would use the `filter()` function using a function that returns true if the type you want and pass in the series.

```
def isInt(element):
    return type(element) == 'int'

filter(isInt, df)

#do what you want after this assuming all elements are ints
```

Comment: So how would I create a new df that includes the int values of the old df and also the converted object to int values of the old df?

Comment: Year Jurisdiction Average scale score
0  2017      Alabama             232.171
1  2017       Alaska             230.456
2  2017      Arizona             234.436
3  2017     Arkansas             233.848
4  2017   California             232.263556                                                               1992\xb9       Virginia             220.763
557  1992\xb9     Washington                   \u2014
558  1992\xb9  West Virginia             215.269
559  1992\xb9      Wisconsin             228.692
560  1992\xb9        Wyoming             225.378

Comment: @Skar_Kod8 I'm afraid I'm a little confused by your problem... Is it important that you have a stream after this part of the code is processed? And is the metadata also important? It seems like you have multiple datapoints that belong together so maybe something where you group the data into tuples would be useful so you have a cohesive type. Hope this helps